# libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type Json::RuntimeError: * Line 1, Column 1 Syntax error: value, object or array expected

Tags: c++, json, parsing, jsoncpp

I am trying to get data from my json document into my main.cpp using Jsoncpp. I am getting this error message :

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type Json::RuntimeError: * Line 1, Column 1
Syntax error: value, object or array expected.

Here is how I'm passing the data on my main.cpp :

```
ifstream file("calibration1114.json");
Json::Value root;
file >> root;

string s = root["sensitivity"].asString();

cout << s << endl
```

Here is my Json file :

```
{"fileName":"2021-08-19T14:40:24-04:00",

"differencedB":-0.02,

"sensitivity":"74.5758204562815678",

"date":"2021-08-19T14:40:24-04:00"}
```

I have also trying parsing data this way on my main.cpp  :

```
ifstream file("calibration1114.json");
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;

bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( file, root );
   if ( !parsingSuccessful )
   {
       cout << "Error parsing the string" << endl;
   }
reader.parse( file, actualJson);

string s = root["sensitivity"].asString();

cout << s << endl;
```

The "Error parsing the string" message shows up.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: After `ifstream file("calibration1114.json");` check that your file was actually opened: `assert(file);` (requires `#include<cassert>`)

Comment: Look at the first bytes in your file. UTF-8 is the only valid encoding for JSON data. Even BOM is not allowed. *JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed
ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8 [RFC3629]. **Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the
beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text.***

Comment: @user17732522 Assertion failed: (file), function main, file main.cpp, line 15. File does not open.

Comment: How does one check the first bytes of the file ? I found nothing online

Comment: @AntoineGaubil There is your problem then. Make sure the file is actually in the working directory (the directory from which the executable is called) and that the user calling the program has read permissions on the file.

Comment: The file is in the working directory AND has read & write permissions. I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: @AntoineGaubil Just to make sure (since this is often misunderstood): Make sure that you actually have the correct working directory: `#include <filesystem>` and `std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path() << "\n";` before you open the file. Is what the program shows you the directory containing the file?

Comment: Yup, I was wrong it wasn't in the correct working directory. Works now thanks for the help!